# Django ORM sort by column, descending, drop dublicates and give the top 5

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, orm

I want to query the top 5 products of a table but they must be unique on the product column, when they have the same value for the column sodium. So its basically sort values by column sodium, show result descending then drop dublicates based on product and only show the first 3 results. I managed to do this on a pandas dataframe but how can i query this via a Django Modell ORM?

This is my example tabel:

```
    brand   product   flavour   sodium
1       01  twister   Tomato    09
2       01  twister   Cheese    15
3       01  crumble   Apple     07
4       02  cream     herbs     17
5       02  cream     orange    17
6       03  chips     smashed   23
7       03  chips     salt      23
8       03  chips     vanilla   23
```

wished Output

```
    brand   product   flavour   sodium
7       03  chips     salt      23
4       02  cream     herbs     17
2       01  twister   Cheese    15
```

At the moment i get this result

```
    brand   product   flavour   sodium
7       03  chips     salt      23
6       03  chips     smashed   23
8       03  chips     vanilla   23
```

Thats what i tried

```
top_product_sodium = Product.objects.all().order_by('-sodium')[:5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use distinct() function to achieve this output.

```
top_product_sodium = Product.objects.values('brand', 'product', 'flavour', 'sodium').distinct().order_by('-sodium')[:5]
```